# Core Data search optimization

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I can't seem to find any discussion about this, but I have this question after I watched session 137 of WWDC about core data optimization.

So, Melissa Turner advise to use <= and < instead of BEGINSWITH, but how do I do that with predicate substitution variables or formatted predicate?

Let's use this example:

```
@"franc" <= searchName AND searchName < @"frand"
```

What if @"franc" is the search keyword variable that is obtained from the search bar text input?

How do I increment the suffix or the overall NSString variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple posted some [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/DerivedProperty/Introduction/Intro.html) that should help.

Comment: Okay, that would be the normalizeString and upperBoundSearchString.